# Redirect to jQuery mobile panel from session PHP

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I want my session PHP to redirect to a jQuery mobile panel within the same page. How would I do that? The issue is, right now the panel opens using 
`<a href="#leftpanel1">`. Can I have my `check.php` page redirect to open the panel?

```
<?php

$user_name = "";
$password = "";     # Important: Change this for live database. 
$database = "";
$server = "";

$user = $_POST['Username'];
$user_pass = $_POST['Password'];

session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

    $query = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '$user' AND password =                '$user_pass'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result); 

    if ($numrows > 0){
        header('Location: /Test.php');
    } else {
        echo 'PAGE NOT FOUND';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to write some jQuery to capture the hash and the trigger the click. So when you are redirected, have a flag or something in the url that jquery can use. like `test.php#open` and then write some jquery to then see the hash and trigger the click of the anchor. Im unsure what the jquery or javascript would be, maybe someoe else here has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some jQuery to capture the hash and the trigger the click. So when you are redirected, have a flag or something in the url that jquery can use. like `test.php#open` and then write some jquery to then see the hash and trigger the click of the anchor.

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // Open
  $("a[hreaf='#leftpanel1'").trigger("click");
} else {
  // Dont open
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me Thanks for trying though. Also, do you have any thoughts on how to tie a variable in a DB to a picture on my server so when that variable is chosen in a select list the pic will show instead of the variable?